# d3 calendar view: how to put all into one svg instead of several svgs

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, calendar, grouping

I am trying to create an export function for 
[D3 Calendar View](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318)

But the problem is that the original code is creating for each month one svg. The export is then only exporting the first svg. How can I make it happen that it is one big svg with all the months inside as group?

The code in question is this:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
.data(d3.range(1990, 2011))
.enter().append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.attr("class", "RdYlGn")
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");
```

Thanks for any ideas.
gb5256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick refactor which places it in a single `svg` and moves each year into it's own `g`.

Sizes become:

```
var width = 960,
    yearHeight = 136, // height of each year
    height = yearHeight * 20, // height of entire svg
    cellSize = 17; // cell size
```

Append initial SVG with large height:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height);
```

Create `g` for each year and translate to position:

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".yearG")
    .data(d3.range(1990, 2011))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class","yearG")
    .attr("class", "RdYlGn")
    .attr("transform", function(d,i){
      return "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + ((yearHeight - cellSize * 7 - 1) + (yearHeight * i)) + ")";
    });
```

Append elements to those `g`s:

```
g.append("text")
...    
var rect = g.selectAll(".day")
...
g.selectAll(".month")
...
```

Here's an [updated gist](http://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/e701d63acb2e1e31b0a3).

Answer (score 2):

If you are not bound by your restriction to put it into one group, you could as well nest all svgs into one outer svg. In this case just one line needed to be changed. Instead of

```
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
```

you would go for

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").selectAll("svg")
```

Your export might then just grab the outer container svg containing all nested svgs.